# Obtaining the Type of the elements in an array of generic type

Tags: c#, arrays, generics, types

I have a generic wrapper class which can sometimes receive an array type as its generic.  I can tell if the supplied generic type is an array by the IsArray property.  But is there a way that I can obtain the type of the array elements in code?  I've looked at all the exposed attributes of a Type object and just not seeing it.

Example:

```
public class wrap<T>
{
    public void doSomething()
    {
        if (typeof(T).IsArray)
            Type arrayElementType = typeof(T).??? ;
    }
}
        // typeof(T) when an array is "int[]"
        // typeof(T).BaseType is "System.Array"
        // how to get "int" out of this?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for the [`Type.GetElementType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getelementtype.aspx) method.

> When overridden in a derived class, returns the Type of the object
>   encompassed or referred to by the current array, pointer or reference
>   type.

```
Type arrayElementType = typeof(T).GetElementType();
```

Comment: Yeah, so, I knew it'd be something absurdly obvious.  My temporary variable was almost the name too.  Thanks a lot for the answer!

Comment: @Devoramadoomalama: Cheers - I remember looking for this for quite some too.